# Pop-up accept button can not be clicked by ROBOT Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have tried to click on a popup window (modal-fade) with an Accept button on it.  The application opens a new tab and pops up with a window simultaneously.  I have tried Switch Window, etc.  Selenium IDE seems to like window handles with it.  Let me know if you need anything else!  Importante!

Again,  on my web application that I m trying to automate the test of in Robot Framework, a new tab opens and popup window occurs s
imultaneously.  I am not sure how to automate the clicking of the Accept button.
Here is the screenshot.

This is the command I am trying:

```
Execute Javascript | document.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='WIN_0_536870909']/div/div")).click()
```

[image: Application Screenshot]

Comment: Look like it's an another Windows popup. Did you try List windows yet ?

Comment: You can give a try to this (not the best, but at least give a try): ```Press Key   \ue004``` and until the select is targeted to "Accept" you use:  ```Press Key   \ue007 ```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was use the Press Keys method and navigated to button.  Then Press Keys Enter.  Press Keys works in a jam.